# Remove manually installed java application

Tags: 14.04, package-management, uninstall

[image]

I had installed an Java application named Visual_Paradigm. Now I want to uninstall it from my Ubuntu 14.04 System.

I couldn’t find the package in synaptic Package Manager.

I know this could be possible duplication but none of the searches helped me!!

Comment: We need to know how you installed it in the first place. When you say "manually", what do you mean?

Comment: I mean, I downloaded a jar file. When I ran it, an installer wizard popped up by which I was able to install that software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Terminal And Type :-

```
 cd /opt/VP_Suite5.0/ 

 sudo ./uninstall
```

Source :- [From svisual-paradigm forum](http://forums.visual-paradigm.com/posts/list/280677.html)

Comment: Ohh Thanx!! That worked !!

A side Question, When we install software manually do they always make a directory in opt?

Comment: Visit here :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649355/what-does-opt-mean-as-in-the-opt-directory-is-it-an-abbreviation